# Javascript: regex get second line from string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to obtain second line from my string. I tried pattern like **/((.*?)\n){2}/**.

```
Some Job Name
1,234 zł - Location

Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle 
poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego drukarza
do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany 
przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym. Spopularyzował 
się w latach 60. XX w. wraz z publikacją arkuszy Letrasetu, zawierających 
fragmenty Lorem Ipsum, a ostatnio z zawierającym różne wersje Lorem Ipsum 
oprogramowaniem przeznaczonym do realizacji druków na komputerach osobistych, 
jak Aldus PageMaker
```

With regex I've tried, output looks like:

```
Some Job Name
1,234 zł - Location

Lorem Ipsum jest tekstem stosowanym jako przykładowy wypełniacz w przemyśle 
poligraficznym. Został po raz pierwszy użyty w XV w. przez nieznanego     drukarza
do wypełnienia tekstem próbnej książki. Pięć wieków później zaczął być używany 
przemyśle elektronicznym, pozostając praktycznie niezmienionym. Spopularyzował 
się w latach 60. XX w. wraz z publikacją arkuszy Letrasetu, zawierających 
fragmenty Lorem Ipsum, a ostatnio z zawierającym różne wersje Lorem Ipsum 
oprogramowaniem przeznaczonym do realizacji druków na komputerach osobistych,
```

just without last line.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ls6Eygt.png

Comment: `/Location.*/s` ?

Comment: but location is for example Paris, Poland, Mexic, Wrocław, Kraków

Comment: Add the language you are using this in, what you tried, and what you should be capturing in the above example.

Comment: That was kinda my point.  You didn't specify what all the rules were.  Based on your extremely limited description of your problem, the pattern I gave works.  I fully assumed that it wasn't really that easy.  But, without further information, it's impossible to give a better solution.

Comment: @StevenDoggart ok, I understand. Sorry for limited description, but I don't really know what to write more about that

Comment: Regex may or may be the solution you need. Is the word "Location", or your language equivalent of it, actually there? Is there any structure to what is shown here as Lorem Ipsum?

Comment: To get the second line in group 1, it's this `(?:\r?\n)([^\r\n]*)` where it can only match the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Given the very little information you've provided, this fits your description.

`\n(.*)\n\n`

Group one is the second line.

See a [demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cR1pS6/2)

Comment: That's nice! Could you help me to obtain only second line? :-)

Comment: @ifeelmyself is that what you want? if not, please provide what you expect the result to be in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a negated character class to capture just the second line.

```
^[^\n]+\n(.+)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sQ7sL9/1

PHP Usage:

```
preg_match('/^[^\n]+\n(.+)/', $string, $secondline);
echo $secondline[1];
```

Demo: https://eval.in/637223

Using `explode` and pulling the second index seems like a cleaner solution to me though.

Explode example:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
echo $lines[1];
```

Demo: https://eval.in/637217