# PHP: Regex to match only the second line

Tags: php, regex

I need to regex only second line of my string. I tried pattern like this:

> /^[^\n]+\n(.+)/

and it doesn't work propertly, it gives me a lot more than just second line.

**String:**

> Front-end developer
>       10,000 zł - Warsaw, Poland
>
> Cześć!
>       Szukamy: Front-end Developera do oddziału 3e Software House w Warszawie (Mokotów obok metra, preferowane), Łodzi (Centrum) lub do
>   pracy zdalnej.
>       Oferujemy: 5-10k za mc (FV / UOD) + benefity, UOP adekwatnie, rozwój w kierunku Node.js
>       Oczekujemy: min. rocznego doświadczenia (RWD, aplikacje single-page)
>       Szczegóły: https://www.3e.pl/praca/programista-front-end-web-developer.html 
>       Kontakt z CV: programista.frontend@praca.3e.pl
>       Praca: Scrum; rozwój i wsparcie frontu w serwisach o bardzo dużej odwiedzalności, zespół jak na zdjęciu.

Comment: If you always need the entire second line, why not explode on "\n" and then get $explode[1] ?

Comment: That looks identical to a pattern I posted on another question, with this same title (or same title for revisions upto 6). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375706/php-regex-to-find-some-words-in-long-string Do you have 2 accounts by chance?

Comment: On the off chance this isn't a duplicate, add your PHP usage, and what the expected output should be.

Comment: Pretty unclear what the issue is, what is being matched and what isn't... A regex101 link would be useful. I used your regex and pasted in the content provided (and removed the second line which is actually an empty line for some reason), and it worked fine for me: https://regex101.com/r/yO0iT4/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is skip the 1st line with the subsequent new line and  empty space:

`Front-end developer 10,000 zł - Warsaw, Poland`

so you can select everything after that:

`Cześć! Szukamy: Front-end Developera do oddziału 3e Software House w Warszawie (Mokotów obok metra, preferowane), Łodzi (Centrum) lub do pracy zdalnej. Oferujemy: 5-10k za mc (FV / UOD) + benefity, UOP adekwatnie, rozwój w kierunku Node.js Oczekujemy: min. rocznego doświadczenia (RWD, aplikacje single-page) Szczegóły: https://www.3e.pl/praca/programista-front-end-web-developer.html Kontakt z CV: programista.frontend@praca.3e.pl Praca: Scrum; rozwój i wsparcie frontu w serwisach o bardzo dużej odwiedzalności, zespół jak na zdjęciu.`

You may want to try:

```
<?php

        $string = "Front-end developer 10,000 zł - Warsaw, Poland

        Cześć! Szukamy: Front-end Developera do oddziału 3e Software House w Warszawie
        (Mokotów obok metra, preferowane), Łodzi (Centrum) lub do pracy zdalnej. Oferujemy: 5-10k za
        mc (FV / UOD) + benefity, UOP adekwatnie, rozwój w kierunku Node.js Oczekujemy: min.
        rocznego doświadczenia (RWD, aplikacje single-page) Szczegóły:
        https://www.3e.pl/praca/programista-front-end-web-developer.html Kontakt z CV:
        programista.frontend@praca.3e.pl Praca: Scrum; rozwój i wsparcie frontu w serwisach o bardzo
        dużej odwiedzalności, zespół jak na zdjęciu.";

        $rx     = '#(.*?\n{2,})(.+)#si';
        $result = preg_replace($rx, "$2", $string);

        var_dump($result);
            // PRODUCES:                
            Cześć! Szukamy: Front-end Developera do oddziału 3e Software House w Warszawie
        (Mokotów obok metra, preferowane), Łodzi (Centrum) lub do pracy zdalnej. Oferujemy: 5-10k za
        mc (FV / UOD) + benefity, UOP adekwatnie, rozwój w kierunku Node.js Oczekujemy: min.
        rocznego doświadczenia (RWD, aplikacje single-page) Szczegóły:
        https://www.3e.pl/praca/programista-front-end-web-developer.html Kontakt z CV:
        programista.frontend@praca.3e.pl Praca: Scrum; rozwój i wsparcie frontu w serwisach o bardzo
        dużej odwiedzalności, zespół jak na zdjęciu.";
```

> Otherwise, if you just wish to **get only the 2nd Line in that Multiline String** you may try using `explode("\n", $string)` as shown below but **since the 2nd Line in your String is empty, we'd extract the 3rd Line (at index 2) instead**:

```
<?php 

        $string     = "Front-end developer 10,000 zł - Warsaw, Poland

        Cześć! Szukamy: Front-end Developera do oddziału 3e Software House w Warszawie
        (Mokotów obok metra, preferowane), Łodzi (Centrum) lub do pracy zdalnej. Oferujemy: 5-10k za
        mc (FV / UOD) + benefity, UOP adekwatnie, rozwój w kierunku Node.js Oczekujemy: min.
        rocznego doświadczenia (RWD, aplikacje single-page) Szczegóły:
        https://www.3e.pl/praca/programista-front-end-web-developer.html Kontakt z CV:
        programista.frontend@praca.3e.pl Praca: Scrum; rozwój i wsparcie frontu w serwisach o bardzo
        dużej odwiedzalności, zespół jak na zdjęciu.";

        $arrLines   = explode("\n", $string);
        $result     = $arrLines[2];
        var_dump($result);
        // PRODUCES:
        '           Cześć! Szukamy: Front-end Developera do oddziału 3e Software House w Warszawie' (length=84)
```